# How can I have human-less authorization and automation with Google Workspace APIs that have access to Google Drive/Sheets APIs in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-sheets-api

Our organization is on Google Workspace enterprise.

We create projects in GCP so we can get tokens to make Google Workspace API calls (Google Drive and Google Sheets).

I want to write a program that will run on a server that will create Google Sheet files in Google Drive by making the appropriate Google Sheets API and Google Drive API calls.

Since this is a human-less automation, we don't have a way for a user to authorize the program to have access to Google Drive and Google Sheets. This program won't be acting on behalf of a user so we can't have the program ask the user to go through the normal Oauth flow.

What options do we have?

I was reading that we can create service IDs in our GCP project but according to https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts-create I can see that service accounts are created in the iam.gserviceaccount.com domain. **The problem is that, for the service account to have access to our Google Drive files we have to whitelist the iam.gserviceaccount.com but if we whitelist iam.gserviceaccount.com then ALL service accounts, even the ones outside of our organization, can access our Google Drive.**

Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: You are correct that service accounts are needed to automate your program. As for service accounts created under the `iam.gserviceaccount.com` domain, it should still fall under user-managed service accounts; these accounts are managed inside the Google Cloud console, but you (and/or other members of your team) will have full control of it.

Comment: You can check out more information regarding the [types of service accounts available here.](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-account-types)

Comment: @MicTest I added some text (bolded) with the issue with service accounts. Please let me know if my understanding is right. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @IMTheNachoMan, thanks for providing additional context regarding your question. Just to ask regarding the whitelisting, is it accessed using a Google Workspace account, since there are [some limitations in whitelisting domains, including service accounts](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6160020#zippy=%2Cadd-a-trusted-domain-to-your-allowlist).

Comment: Can I ask if you have also tried to share the files to the service account's associated email address to provide access?

Comment: @MicTest The link you sent me says "Google service accounts (domain name ends with "gserviceaccount.com") can't be used as trusted domains." but it does not provide any detail. This means we can't use service accounts. And can't share the file with the email since we can't whitelist the service account domain.

Comment: I've tried replicating it on my end, and you should be able to share your Google Drive file/s to the service account email address without the need of whitelisting it; this allows the service account to access the said file/s.

Comment: Wait, so you're saying if we create a service account, we can share the Google Drive with just that service account WITHOUT having to whitelist the service account domain?

Comment: Yes, as long as the files on Google Drive are shared with the service account's email address, the account will be able to access it without the need of whitelisting the domain.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder how you did that since Google Drive won't let you share a file with a  domain that's not in the whitelist.

Comment: @MicTest In your test, is your Google Drive configured to not be accessible by folks outside your domain?

Comment: @MicTest Can you share details of your test? When I try, it does not work. I get the error `Sorry, an item cannot be shared outside of [redacted]`.